# How to add addional HFS+ partitions after installing Windows with Bootcamp

Tags: bootcamp, disk-utility, partition, dual-boot, hfs+

The goal is to create a few extra HFS+ partitions after running the Bootcamp utility while not breaking Bootcamp's boot-ability. I am Running OS X El Capitain, and I only have a single disk drive to work with in a MacBook Pro.

*The goal is to have a partition layout something like the following*

CurrentMacOS

Windows Bootcamp

ExtraHFS1

ExtraHFS2

...

So far I have tried installing OS X, then doing BootCamp then adding partitions in disk utility, which breaks bootcamp. Also it seems bootcamp assistant will not work if there are multiple HFS partions already existing. 
So the whole process is kind of terrible.